# How to attach a relationship directly on an object?

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know if I formulated the question correctly, but whatever.

So when I use the "store" method on my controller, I send two fields, "name" and "fr", both in the same request.
In my controller, I want to be able to create my Model (Room) and attach its relationship to it (RoomTranslation). When I try the following code, it tells me I didn't provide the room_id. Is there an automatic way to achieve this ?

```
    public function store(RoomRequest $request)
    {
        $request = $request->validated();
        $room = new Room;
        $room->create($request);
        $room->translations()->create($request);
        return success('');
    }
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RoomTranslation extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['fr', 'room_id'];

    public function room() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Room');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\RoomTranslation;

class Room extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function categories() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category');
    }

    public function translations() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\RoomTranslation');
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help !

P.S. : If there is a cleaner way to write this part of my code, I will be happy to hear how I can improve it.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Room::create($request->only(['name']))->translations()->create($request->only(['fr']));
```

just look for typo or input names to be correct.

Also in Room model class translations relation if you have multiple languages for every Room should be **hasMany**, And if you don't have many translations per Room you could just add a column for translation language.